# How to make five different colours width equal in my drawable that the layout will use as a background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have created five different colours in my drawable, however, when the background shows on the android handheld the colour width is not equal for each colour.

My goal is to make each colour width equal in the drawable level.

This is what I like to achieve:

[image: This is what I like to achieve]

Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:right="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="250dp" android:width="50dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/red_background_70_lighter"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="250dp" android:width="50dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="100dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="250dp" android:width="50dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="150dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="250dp" android:width="50dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="200dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="250dp" android:width="50dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

        <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="0dp" android:left="0dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            </shape>
        </item>


</layer-list>
```

This is what I have on the Android HH at the moment:

[image: Android HH Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
1.. create 9 patch png image (containing equal width rectangles) ..
2.. set created file as background..

Hope this  works..
for using 9 patch.. here is the link
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch
.. as you mentioned it will slow down the recycler view...  here is another apprach.. nest constraint layout in your view (I have nested it in Relative Layout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropables"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dropables"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/holder1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/holder2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/holder1"
          
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/holder3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blueShade"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/holder2"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/holder4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/holder3"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Actucal_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:text="Your Text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
        

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           />

       
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used text view as holder for background color .. if u want to change color of specific strip. change color of that "holder" programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I thought about using an image, however, that can rapidly slow down the recycler view when I have more than 3,000 records.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: modified the answer by nesting Costraintlayout inside Relative Layout.